# Excircle and incircle proof

Tags: geometry

> Prove that if the incircle of triangle $ABC$ touches side $BC$ at $D$ and the $A$-excircle touches side $BC$ at $D'$, then the midpoint of $BC$ is the midpoint of $DD'$.

This is an interesting property that I discovered when doing a few problems but the solutions didn't prove it. After drawing several triangles and their in- and excircles, it seems to be true that the midpoint of the intouch and and extouch points is in fact the midpoint of the side of the triangle.

As another question, if anyone can prove that the antipode of the intouch $D$ which I have labeled as $U$ in the triangle below is collinear with the exsimilicenter $A$ and $D'$ that would help. Finally, is it also true that $A,U,D',$ and $I_a$ are collinear or just $A,U,$ and $D'$? 
[image]

Note: $I_a$ is the center of the $A$-exircle.

Comment: You wrote "incenter." Did you mean "incircle"? Also, "touches" might be better than "intersects" in that case.

Comment: @David Yes, that was a typo. That would be impossible, anyway.

Comment: Are you sure that your definition of $D$ and $D'$ is the same throughout your question and in the illustration?

Comment: @David Yep. An intouch is the point of contact between the incircle and its triangle.

Comment: First you call the intouch $D'$ and later $D$.

Comment: @David Sorry for that. I fixed it now.

Answer (score 2):

I will answer the first question.

This is easy to prove using just one basic idea: when a circle is tangent to two sides of an angle, the distance from the vertex to each of the points of tangency is the same.

Applying that idea to the incircle, you'll find after some calculations that $BD = \frac{1}{2}(a + c - b)$. Applying it to the excircle opposite vertex $A$, you'll find $CD' = \frac{1}{2}(a + c - b) = BD$.

For the second question, the dilation $h$ with centre $A$ taking $I$ to $I_a$ transforms the incircle into the excircle. It also transforms line $ID$ into a parallel line passing through $I_a$. Since $ID$ and $I_aD'$ are both perpendicular to $BC$, the image of line $ID$ must be line $I_a D'$. Points $U$ and $D$ are the intersections of the incircle with $ID$. They must be carried by $h$ to the intersections of the excircle with $I_a D'$. Since $h$ has positive ratio, $U$ must be carried to $D'$. This proves that $A, U, D'$ are aligned.

Assume $I_a$ is on line $AD'$. Then since $I_a D'$ and $UD$ are both perpendicular to $BC$ and pass through $U$, we must have $D = D'$. This shows that $AI$ is is perpendicular to $BC$, hence that $ABC$ is isosceles.

Comment: I got it thanks!

Comment: Can you try the second part?

Comment: I don't get the last sentence: how does the proof make it apparent that $I_a$ is on line $AD'$ if and only if $ABC$ is isosceles?

Answer (score 0):

> *Finally, is it also true that A, U, D’, and I<sub>a</sub> are collinear, or just A, U, and D’ ?*

*I<sub>a</sub>* is **not** collinear with the other three, unless the triangle is isosceles. As an aside, the points *A*, *D*, and *U’* are also collinear, where *U’* is the antipode of *D’* with regard to *I<sub>a</sub>*. Also, $DU\parallel D'U'.$

Comment: If we let $P$ be the point on line $AI$ for which $MD = MP$, is it true that $DPQD'$ is a cyclic quadrilateral with circumcenter $M$?

Comment: @Puzzled417: What is *Q* ?

Comment: $Q$ is a point on the incircle such that $\angle{AQD} = 90^{\circ}$.

Comment: @Puzzled417: You can answer this and many other such questions for yourself using [*GeoGebra*](http://web.geogebra.org/#algebra). :-$)$

Comment: Yes, but what is the geometrical reason why?

Comment: @Puzzled417: The geometrical reason for what ?

Comment: I am referring to this question: Let $ABC$ be a non-isosceles triangle with incenter $I$ whose incircle is tangent to $\overline{BC}$, $\overline{CA}$, $\overline{AB}$ at $D$, $E$, $F$, respectively. Denote by $M$ the midpoint of $\overline{BC}$. Let $Q$ be a point on the incircle such that $\angle AQD = 90^{\circ}$. Let $P$ be the point inside the triangle on line $AI$ for which $MD = MP$. Prove that either $\angle PQE = 90^{\circ}$ or $\angle PQF = 90^{\circ}$.

Comment: Here is the solution: Part 1: WLOG assume that $AC >AB.$ A-excircle $(I_a)$ touches $BC$ at $D'$ and $U$ is the antipode of $D$ WRT $(I).$ As $A$ is the exsimilicenter of $(I) \sim (I_a),$ it follows that $A,U,D'$ are collinear. Thus if $AUD'$ cuts $(I)$ again at $Q',$ we have $\angle UQ'D \equiv \angle AQ'D=90^{\circ}$ $\Longrightarrow$ $Q \equiv Q'.$ Since $M$ is also midpoint of $DD',$ then $DPQD'$ is cyclic with circumcenter $M.$

Comment: Part 2: Note that $P$ is intersection of $AI$ with the B-midline of $\triangle ABC,$ thus it is on $DE$ (well-known). Hence $\angle PQE=\angle UQE+\angle UQP=\angle UDE+\angle EDC=90^{\circ},$ as desired.