# For a given $\triangle ABC$, construct a $\triangle A'B'C'$ that has $\triangle ABC$ as its extouch triangle

Tags: geometry, triangle-centres

> For a given $\triangle ABC$, construct a $\triangle A'B'C'$, so that the $\triangle ABC$ is the *extouch triangle* of $\triangle A'B'C'$.

The [*extouch triangle*](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/ExtouchTriangle.html) is the triangle formed by the points of tangency of the excircles with their corresponding sides.

Thanks!

Comment: Is there a connection with the property given in: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1623168 ?

Comment: There might be, but it is still not enough for me to solve the problem. I will look more into it anyway. Thanks.

Comment: For a given triangle ABC, the ex-center (wrt $\angle ABC$) can always be found. By dropping perpendiculars from that excenter to the sides (extended if necessary), the vertices of  that extouch triangle can be found.

Comment: You are right, but my question is different. I ask, assume you are only given the intersection points of those perpendiculars from the excenters to the sides, can you find the original triangle?

Comment: Please show the own effort to solve this problem. Else the problem is missing context. (There is no picture, there is no reference, no idea to attack. Else the notation is slightly irritating, since i always start with a triangle $\Delta ABC$, and construct from this one some $\Delta A'B'C'$, but this is my problem.)